# How to get cell data from button pressed event (Custom tableview cell)

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, ios4

There is a button and label on my custom tableview cell. This is how Im set the button action.

```
[cell.btnPlus addTarget: self action: @selector(plusButtonPressed) forControlEvents: UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
```

This method is working fine. I want to get the label text of the cell which the button is pressed.

How could I do it?

Answer (score 0):

Either add a property to the button that points to the cell, or, if btnPlus is a subview of cell, use `btnPlus.superview.textlabel.text`.

Answer (score 0):

> set the tag to that button and label then you can get that label text
>   using view with tag option

Answer (score 0):

change @selector(plusButtonPressed) to @selector(plusButtonPressed:) (note the added colon at the end)

then in your

```
- (void)plusButtonPressed:(UIButton*)sender {
    NSString *theText = sender.superview.textlabel.text;
}
```

(this is assuming the plus button is added to the contentView of the UITableViewCell)

Comment: Thing is that I create the custom cell as separate class like this.  CustomCell *cell = (CustomCell *)[[tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier: CustomCellIdentifier] autorelease];  if (cell == nil) { 
  NSArray *nib = [[NSBundle mainBundle] loadNibNamed:@"CustomCell"
              owner:self options:nil];
  for (id oneObject in nib) if ([oneObject isKindOfClass:[CustomCell class]])
   cell = (CustomCell *)oneObject;
  
 }

Comment: If you're using an Xib with the cell, instead of creating the action in code, wire it up in Interface Builder to go to a selector in the CustomCell class, then you can just access the self.textLabel.text property directly

Comment: Yes, I have separate class with Xib. But how can I retreive text label from this class (not Customcell class). If you can give me a code example, its highly appreciated, coz Im still new to iOS SDK

Answer (score 0):

set tag to cell:

```
cell.contentView.tag = indexPath.row+10000*indexPath.section; //or any you like
[cell.contentView addSubview:button];
```

then, in button's callback:

```
int raw=0;
int section=0;
long tag = [sender superview].tag;
NSLog(@"tag: %ld", tag);
for (int i = 0; i<[data count]; i++) {
    if (tag>=10000) 
    {
        tag-=10000;
        section++;
    }
    else i = [data count];
}
raw = tag;
```

now, you have full access to your cell. use calculated `raw` and `section` ta get access to cell.